# Appending a Query String to the End of a Function Action URL

Tags: php, forms, query-string

For the code below, I would like to append `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` to the end of index.php.  But when I try to do it, it makes the code return a blank page.  So I think I might be doing it wrong.

How can I correctly make this appendage?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
    <?php

    function show_loginform($disabled = false)
    {

        echo '<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="./index.php"> 

    ...

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
echo '<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="./index.php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'">';
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer, a very common mistake is to assume that $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] contains the question mark as well the query string. Actually, you must add in the question mark manually, as webbiedave has done.

Comment: This works unless his blank-page is caused by a PHP error and not a 404

Comment: @webdestroya : OP's question implies that the page blankness is caused when attempting to append the query string. This answer shows him how to do it correctly. If other problems are found to exist, he can post a different question.

Answer (score 1):

hmmmm. Can you spell XSS?

I'd recommend going with this is a more safer option:

```
$url='./index.php';
$qry=array();
$join='';
foreach ($_GET as $name=>$val) {
   $join='?';
   $qry[]=urlencode($name) . '=' . urlencode($val);
}
$url.=$join . implode('&',$qry);
print "<....action='$url'>";
```